# Defining Integers in Column Class breaks/skips the Table Cell Renderer?

Tags: java, tablecellrenderer

After managing to get my columns to sort by defining the Column Classes - my Cell Render now only applies to Columns that contain String values and not applied to the Integer columns?

[This is what it looks like: ("% of target reached" is the Integer Column seen as white - should not be white)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGFdL.png)

This shows you Column class definitions for String and Integer Classes:

```
    JTable  compTable5 = new JTable();
    compTable5.setEnabled(false);
    DefaultTableModel model5 = new DefaultTableModel(){
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return Integer.class;

                default:
                    return String.class;

            }
        }
    };
```

This is the Renderer

```
compTable5.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                       Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

            int status = (int)table.getValueAt(row, 1);
            String status2 = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 5);

            if ("Not Used".equals(status2)) {setBackground(Color.lightGray);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status2.equals("Priority 1")) {setBackground(scaleRed);}
            else if ( status == 0 && !status2.equals("Working") && !status2.equals("Not Used") && !status2.equals("Priority 1")) {setBackground(pink);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status < 20) {setBackground(scaleRed);}
            else if (status >= 20 && status < 40) {setBackground(scaleOrange);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status >= 40 && status < 60) {setBackground(scaleYellow);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status >= 60 && status < 80) {setBackground(scaleGreen1);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status >= 80 && status < 100) {setBackground(scaleGreen2);setForeground(Color.black);}
            else if (status > 100) {setBackground(scaleBlue);setForeground(Color.white);}
            else {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }

            return this;
        }
    });
```

I am a java noob and this is my first stackoverflow post, thanks for all the help you all have given already given me on this forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTable` most likely uses a special `TableCellRenderer` for Integers (and Doubles, Floats, Longs) to display the values right-aligned instead of the default left-aligned.

You bind your `DefaultTableCellRenderer` for `Object.class`, which is a fall-back if no more specialized TableCellRenderer is found.

Try to bind your DefaultTableCellRenderer both to `Object.class` and to `Integer.class`, like this:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer myRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
  // all your code for the cell renderer, as in your example
}
compTable5.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, myRenderer);
compTable5.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, myRenderer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that fixed my problem!